# Convert jsonb postgres column data to String

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I have a column of jsonb in Postgres.

Which contains data like `"{\" name\":\"xyz\"}"`. I want to convert it as `{"name":"xyz"}`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify what exactly you want to do?
If you need to remove whitespaces in Java you can try something like [this](https://github.com/mfvanek/pg-index-health-demo/blob/58788ebc6c4a354792de232828c0dc3f5c8da749/src/test/java/io/github/mfvanek/pg/index/health/demo/JsonbTest.java#L25).

```
        try (final Connection connection = embeddedPostgres.getTestDatabase().getConnection();
         final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         final PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update your_table set your_column = ? where id = ?")) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try (final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from your_table order by id limit 10")) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                final long id = resultSet.getLong("id");
                final String infoAsString = resultSet.getString("info");

                final String withoutWhitespaces = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(infoAsString);
                final PGobject fixedInfoObject = new PGobject();
                fixedInfoObject.setType("jsonb");
                fixedInfoObject.setValue(withoutWhitespaces);
                updateStatement.setObject(1, fixedInfoObject);
                updateStatement.setLong(2, id);
                updateStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        connection.commit();
    }
```